# Create Visual hills (spikes) javascript map

Tags: javascript, dictionary

How can I create dynamic javascript map like this using javascript?

[image]

Source: http://content.time.com/time/interactive/0,31813,1549966,00.html

Comment: You could use the Google Maps API, adjust tilt, and use your own dynamic custom markers depending on a value associated with the place.

Comment: Use [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).